How is $R_{ZZ}(\pi/2)$ gate maximally entangling?
IBM Qiskit website says $R_{ZZ}$ gate is maximally entangling at $\theta = \pi/2$.
But acting $R_{ZZ}$ on two qubits initialized as $ |00 \rangle $ still remains $ |00 \rangle $ so it is separable in the form of  $ |0 \rangle \otimes |0 \rangle $.
Doesn't this show that $R_{ZZ}$ is far from being entangling at $\theta = \pi/2$? (or for any value of $\theta$ for that matter)?

No, it doesn't. I think most people would call a unitary "maximally entangling" if it sends some product state to some maximally entangled state. It certainly doesn't have to produce a maximally entangling state on every input. That's impossible by invertibility$^1$.
Note that CNOT also fixes $|00\rangle$ and it is a paradigmatic example of maximally entangling gate. Incidentally, $R_{ZZ}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and CNOT are equivalent$^2$ under local unitaries.

$^1$ Invertibility implies that every $n$-qubit unitary produces every possible $n$-qubit pure state on some input. In particular, every two-qubit unitary produces $|00\rangle$ on some input.
$^2$ Exercise.

